# vector orthogonal to all but one element of a linearly independent list

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

In Cox's paper 'The Homogeneous Co-ordinate ring of a toric variety'
he makes the statement: $\{u_\rho : \rho \in \sigma(1)\}\subset \mathbb{Z^n}$ is linearly independnet and thus there must exist $m\in M$ such that:

$\langle m ,u_\rho \rangle$ > 0 and $\langle m ,u_{\rho^{'}} \rangle = 0$ for all $\rho^{'}\in \sigma(1)\backslash \{\rho\}$

here $\sigma$ is a cone with $\sigma(1)$ being its one dimensional sub-cones, $\rho$, each with primative generator $u_\rho \in \mathbb{Z}$. M is the cocharacter lattice of the toric variety defined by the cone $\sigma$ and thus also isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$. the inner product is therefore the usual dot product.

I can't see why this must be true, is it due to the correspondence between monomials and characters of the torus or is this a linear algebra result?

Answer (score 1):

The problem for $\mathbb Z^n$ can be solved through linear algebra. Hopefully $M$ being isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^n$ means the solution carries over.

Let $x_i$ be a set of $n$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb Z^n$. We first want to find a vector $r\in\mathbb Q^n$ with $\langle r, x_1\rangle = 1$ and $\langle r, x_i\rangle = 0, 2 \le i \le n$. This can be solved with standard linear algebra methods. The components of $r$ can then all be put on a common denominator $d$. Multiply $r$ by $d$ to get a vector $m$ in $\mathbb Z^n$ with $\langle m, x_1\rangle = d > 0$ and $\langle m, x_i\rangle = 0, 2 \le i \le n$